# Can I use python 3.5.2 on my machine for development if the client is 3.4?

Tags: python, programming-practices, ruby

Here is the situation, I wish to use the last programming language of ruby, python and some more on my development machine, but the server where it will be is not last version of that programming language.

Does that will create troubles?

Comment: Whether it will create trouble depends entirely on what your program does; whether it is impacted by any of the bug fixes or new features in the version of python you're using vs. what's available in the production environment, with the same applied to any dependencies. You'll need to test it on 3.4 before sending it to the client, surely, and developing it yourself on the correct version just saves you that headache / additional time sink.

Comment: Do you think it would be careful to use up-to-date version on production servers? Do you think it would be better to install software collection on the production server to be able to follow my way of development?

Comment: I think that the production server probably keeps to stable versions, or versions tested against their OS / setup and other applications running on it. If they've made a point of telling you it needs to work in 3.4; they probably have their reasons for it, and it's unlikely whatever your project is a) actually requires version x.x.x; b) is important enough for them to (potentially) break support for existing applications; c) is important enough for them to risk running software unsupported by RHEL or whatever their OS support arrangements are.

Comment: Ok thanks for you lights, this reponse is clear and I wish to give you a point @TZHX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly has the potential to create problems, yes. If you knowingly or unknowingly use a feature that has changed between versions, then your production and development systems can give different results. You might have tests that pass in development that will fail in production.